# Will this work? Adding an alias domain and moving primary domain MX to M365

Tags: email, google-workspace, mx, microsoft

So we have a special extenuating situation. We have a business we've had for 20 years using example1.com and we're being forced by our contract to switch and use M365 encrypted email but the entire business runs on Google Workspace. My idea is to buy a second domain example.com and add it as an alias in workspace with the MX records connected to Google and switching the primary domain MX to M365. So all future email is handled on M365 but users can still login to Workspace using @example1.com and still use all Google for our business as we have for 10 years.

1. The question is, will this work? I have apprehensions that some purchased add-ons, like Form Publisher may break on things like their workflows with email notifications. And GCPW is used on computers.
2. Will we still receive notifications on M365 for Google doc approval requests using Google workspace?
3. Will comment notifications still be sent to users on the M365 email?
4. Does GmailApp.sendEmail still allow you to change sender to your alias domain instead of primary?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Its very difficult to answer this question based on how broad the information provided is.  One comment that may be of use - you can't have a CNAME and other records for the same domain - so if bt an alias you mean CNAME record then this will not work - you would need to use A records instead.

Comment: No. Google Workspace allows you to add secondary alias domains in the workspace account that are nested under the primary.